# How to access var variable in foreach tag in custom tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How to access var value of foreach tag in a custom tag?

```
<c:foreach items=“{collection}” var=“items”>
    <custom:tag name=items />
</foreach>
```

How can I assign value of var to attribute name in custom tag?

I used `pageContext.getAttribute(\"item"\)` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:foreach items=“{collection}” var=“items”>
    <c:set var="itemsToPass" value="${items}"/>
    <% pageContext.setAttribute("forEachVar", itemsToPass); %>
    <custom:tag name="${pageScope.forEachVar}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

You can use `${pageScope.forEachVar}` in your tag (remember to cast it to whatever you need, for example use `pageContext.getAttribute(...)` to cast the Object to String like `String itemsName= (String) pageContext.getAttribute("forEachVar");`).